# How to make routing changes permanent

Tags: routing, openvpn, isc-dhcpd

I have the below routing rules to apply once tun0 comes up (which is a openvpn tunnel).  These rules help push some clients on my network outside the VPN and direct to the internet. What is the best way to apply these?

Update: Running Ubuntu 18.04.

```
ip route add default via 192.168.8.1 table novpn
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0 table novpn
ip rule add from 192.168.1.220 table novpn
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.210-192.168.1.220 -o enp5s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Please add Linux distro.

Answer (score 2):

You can run commands from openvpn config like:

```
script-security 2
up /path/to/routing/script
down /path/to/routing/downscript
```

from man openvpn:

> ```
>    --up cmd
>           Run command cmd after successful TUN/TAP device open (pre --user
>           UID change).
>
>           cmd  consists  of  a path to script (or executable program), op‐
>           tionally followed by arguments. The path and  arguments  may  be
>           single-  or  double-quoted and/or escaped using a backslash, and
>           should be separated by one or more spaces.
>
>           The up command is useful for  specifying  route  commands  which
>           route IP traffic destined for private subnets which exist at the
>           other end of the VPN connection into the tunnel.
>
>           For --dev tun execute as:
>
>           cmd  tun_dev  tun_mtu  link_mtu  ifconfig_local_ip  ifconfig_re‐
>           mote_ip [ init | restart ]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (add it to `/etc/rc.local`)

```
ip route add default via 192.168.8.1 table novpn
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0 table novpn
ip rule add from 192.168.1.220 table novpn
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.210-192.168.1.220 -o enp5s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance....but what if I have no /etc/rc.local?  I'm on Ubuntu 18.04,